# Keep empty string instead of null for /copy command

Tags: postgresql, bulkcopy

When using the `\copy` command with `psql` I have a file with empty values. These values are not to be `null` but instead always an empty string.

My command:

```
\copy agltransact FROM 'dbo_agltransact.csv' with null as '' CSV HEADER;
```

The error I get:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "apar_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I have this data:

```
account,amount,apar_id,apar_type
14015,3000000.000,,1
14015,3000000.000,,2
```

I want the next to last columns to be an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I need to escape and output the single quotes

```
\copy agltransact FROM 'dbo_agltransact.csv' with null as E'\'\'' CSV HEADER;
```